# Not able to delete in auto format with javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, date, date-formatting

1.

Here is [original auto format date](https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/KMWqRr) made by someone else,

so the date is like `12 / 12 / 2019`, we use `space / space` to separate the number.

2.

I want to use format like `12/12/2019` with following, but it seems I am not able to delete.

[This is the code pen I have](https://codepen.io/kenpeter/pen/xxxKKNw)

```
var outV = v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + "/" : v;
```

This is the new code I have

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        /* box */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* family */
        font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
        /* smooth */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }

      /* all box */
      *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      /* body bg */
      body {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
      }

      /* form */
      form {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 60px auto;
      }

      /* form input */
      form input {
        /* big box */
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        width: 100%;
        color: #666;
        line-height: 3;
        border-radius: 7px;
        font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      form input:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }
      form input.error {
        border-color: #ff0000;
      }
      form label.error {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 6px;
        font-size: 11px;
      }

      label {
        color: #999;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
      }

      /* use small */
      form small {
        color: #888;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        align-self: ;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/KMWqRr -->
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
      <label for="amount">Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="date" />
      <small>Enter date as Day / Month / Year</small>
    </form>
  </body>

  <script>
    // input date by id
    var date = document.getElementById("date");

    // check val, str?, max?
    function checkValue(str, max) {
      // 1. 02, we don't check, because 0->12 (month) or 0->31
      // 2. 00, we check
      if (str.charAt(0) !== "0" || str == "00") {
        //test
        console.log("&& in");

        // str to num
        var num = parseInt(str);

        // 1. not a number (below code, already filter out \D)
        // 2. # <= 0, e.g. -1
        // 3. 32 > 21 in month
        // default to 1
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;

        // 1. month: 3 > 12's 1st char ==> 03
        // 2. month: 1 <= 12's 1st char ===> 1.toStr, later more #
        // 3. day: 2 <= 31's 1st chr ===> 2.toStr, later more #
        str =
          num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1
            ? "0" + num // self, no more #
            : num.toString(); // can be more num
      }
      return str;
    }

    // user typing
    date.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
      //test
      console.log("=== listen input ====", this.value);

      // date input type is text
      this.type = "text";
      // date input value to var
      var input = this.value;

      // del is \D, non-digit
      // e.g. 02/ -> del 2 -> actual del 2/ -> 0 (left)
      //if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) {
      if (/\/$/.test(input)) {
        //test
        console.log("--digi slash--", input);

        // substr, last exclude, len-3
        input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);

        //test
        console.log("--digi slash after--", input);
      }

      // remove non-digi
      var values = input.split("/").map(function(v) {
        // \D is not digit, so replace not digit to ""
        var replacedV = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
        return replacedV;
      });

      // e.g.
      // month, day
      // values == ["01", "12"]

      // check date, may not have
      if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 31);

      // check month, may not have
      if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 12);

      var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
        // test
        console.log("*** add slash", i);

        //var outV = v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + " / " : v;
        var outV = v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + "/" : v;

        return outV;
      });

      // join everything,
      console.log("output", output);
      console.log("substr", output.join("").substr(0, 14));

      // e.g. 01/01/1992 ==> 9 chars
      // 01 / 01 / 1992 ==> 13 chars
      this.value = output.join("").substr(0, 14);

      console.log(">>> this.value", this.value);
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: your modification seems to work, it formats the date as per your desired format. am I understanding something wrong? https://jsfiddle.net/shrys/3trdmhux/

Comment: @shrys see my change above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the original pen, there is a space between slashes. So when the user deletes a space, we can check if the last character is a "/" and the deletes the character before that.

In your case there is no space. At any point, your change listener gets called with a last character as number.

So you can't use this approach. In this case I would suggest, track previous value and use it to delete a character before "/".

Example `if prevValue = "12/12/"` and user hits a delete, input listener gets called with value 12/12. At this point you can't decide whether its a delete or insert.

You can use previous input to tackle this `if (prevInput.length > input.length && /\d\/$/.test(prevInput)) {`

If you need a codepen, added below.

https://codepen.io/nithinthampi/pen/XWWrJRz

Final solution below. Hope this helps!

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        /* box */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        /* family */
        font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
        /* smooth */
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      }

      /* all box */
      *,
      *:before,
      *:after {
        box-sizing: inherit;
      }

      /* body bg */
      body {
        background-color: #f3f3f3;
      }

      /* form */
      form {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 60px auto;
      }

      /* form input */
      form input {
        /* big box */
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        width: 100%;
        color: #666;
        line-height: 3;
        border-radius: 7px;
        font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      form input:focus {
        outline: 0;
      }
      form input.error {
        border-color: #ff0000;
      }
      form label.error {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 6px;
        font-size: 11px;
      }

      label {
        color: #999;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 18px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0.05em;
      }

      /* use small */
      form small {
        color: #888;
        font-size: 1em;
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/KMWqRr -->
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
      <label for="amount">Date</label>
      <input type="text" id="date" />
      <small>Enter date as Day / Month / Year</small>
    </form>
  </body>

  <script>
    // input date by id
    var date = document.getElementById("date");

    // check val, str?, max?
    function checkValueWrapper() {
      var prevValue = "";
      return function updatePrevValue(newValue) {
        prevValue = newValue;
      };
    }

    function checkValue(str, max) {
      // 1. 02, we don't check, because 0->12 (month) or 0->31
      // 2. 00, we check
      if (str.charAt(0) !== "0" || str == "00") {
        //test
        console.log("&& in");

        // str to num
        var num = parseInt(str);

        // 1. not a number (below code, already filter out \D)
        // 2. # <= 0, e.g. -1
        // 3. 32 > 21 in month
        // default to 1
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;

        // 1. month: 3 > 12's 1st char ==> 03
        // 2. month: 1 <= 12's 1st char ===> 1.toStr, later more #
        // 3. day: 2 <= 31's 1st chr ===> 2.toStr, later more #
        str =
          num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1
            ? "0" + num // self, no more #
            : num.toString(); // can be more num
      }
      return str;
    }

    function wrapEventListener() {
      var prevInput = "";
      return function(e) {
        //test
        console.log("=== listen input ====", this.value);

        // date input type is text
        this.type = "text";
        // date input value to var
        var input = this.value;

        // del is \D, non-digit
        // e.g. 02/ -> del 2 -> actual del 2/ -> 0 (left)
        //if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) {
        //if prevInput length id greate e
        if (prevInput.length > input.length && /\d\/$/.test(prevInput)) {
          //test
          console.log("--digi slash--", input);

          // substr, last exclude, len-3
          input = input.substr(0, input.length - 1);

          //test
          console.log("--digi slash after--", input);
        }

        // remove non-digit
        var values = input.split("/").map(function(v) {
          // \D is not digit, so replace not digit to ""
          var replacedV = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
          return replacedV;
        });

        // e.g.
        // month, day
        // values == ["01", "12"]

        // check date, may not have
        if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 31);

        // check month, may not have
        if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 12);

        var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
          // test
          console.log("*** add slash", i);

          //var outV = v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + " / " : v;
          var outV = v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + "/" : v;

          return outV;
        });

        // join everything,
        console.log("output", output);
        console.log("substr", output.join("").substr(0, 14));

        // e.g. 01/01/1992 ==> 9 chars
        // 01 / 01 / 1992 ==> 13 chars
        this.value = output.join("").substr(0, 14);
        prevInput = this.value;

        console.log(">>> this.value", this.value);
      };
    }

    // user typing
    date.addEventListener("input", wrapEventListener());
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: The code snippet produces a script error. The codepen version seems dysfunctional. Entering "1/1/2011" ends up being "11/02/011". Entering say "12/12" then using the cursor key to position the insertion put to after the first 2, then pressing delete shows "112/" with the insertion point after the slash. Pasting "1/1/2011" is converted to ""112011". Pressing "/" changes it to "1". And so on…

Comment: @RobG Appreciate the suggestions and yes those are perfectly valid arguments. The question was about "Not able to delete in auto format with javascript" and I was trying to address only that. The original pen which he was trying to mimic has all these shortfalls too.

Comment: @kenpeter Please note the above points from RobG. The original pen you trying to copy has many shortcomings, which you might need to address.

Comment: @RobG, Copy and paste will be in the backlog. Pressing "/" change to 1, will be in backlog. Customer comes back to me, they want to resolve the deletion when the cursor in the middle of string. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: @nithin, Copy and paste will be in the backlog. Pressing "/" change to 1, will be in backlog. Customer comes back to me, they want to resolve the deletion when the cursor in the middle of string. Do you have any idea to fix it?

Comment: I'll take a look